# Docker container can't connect to ip host

Tags: docker, hystrix

I have deployed a netflix hystrix dashboard with turbine on a docker container, I can access to `http://ip:8081/hystrix` but when I try to monitor the stream of turbine it freeze and doesn't return any information, I test using curl inside the container and execute `curl http://localhost:8081/turbine.stream` and `curl http://containername:8081/turbine.stream`, with those two command works perfectly but when I use the host ip as `curl http://hostip:8081/turbine.stream` the curl throws `Failed to connect to hostip port 8081: No route to host`, I can't found a solution, can someone help me with this issue?,

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In order to access the container through Host IP you need to ensure the following:

1. Port mapping is allowing through the Host/Public IP itself not only localhost.

   > You can check this by executing `docker ps` on the docker host and look for the `PORTS` column the default should be as the following `0.0.0.0:8081->8081/tcp` which means it can accept connection from any interface either public, private or localhost.
2. The firewall is not blocking the connection on port `8081`.

   > By default the firewall of the host should be managed by Docker daemon itself so the port 8081 will be allowed in the firewall but you might have a different case either Docker is not managing the firewall of the host or there is an extra layer that prevents the connection